# Spring Boot - Change Transaction Manager handling @Transactional annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I'm currently using the `@Transactional` annotation to save data to a database, and would like to know how to change the transaction so it affects other resources like message queues. I didn't set up beans or anything to make dealing with the database transactional - I just added the `@Transactional` annotation and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking to enter complicated and slow world called two phase commit transactions. For such case you would need to use distributed transactions manager like [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/Main/WebHome). JEE has [JTA (Java Transaction API)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) abstractions for it.

I would suggest to avoid this world as much as possible, because of slowness.

[Here are few Spring Boot examples I created](https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/07-jta). They combine distributed transactions with database and JMS queue.

Combining even more than two data sources into distributed transactions would be extremely slow.